# Scons plugin in Eclipse cannot find scons executable

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, build, scons

I'm installing Scons to be used in an Eclipse project on Windows. I've installed the Sconsolidator plugin for Eclipse, but that plugin is asking me for the path to the Scons executable.

I've tried both `scons.bat` and `scons.py` in `C:\Python33\Scripts`, but neither of them seem to solve the problem.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: SCons does not support Python 3: http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#What_version_of_Python_do_I_need.3F

Comment: OK I've reinstalled everything with Python 2.7 and this problem is solved. @darthbith could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SCons does not support Python 3: http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#What_version_of_Python_do_I_need.3F